# Is there an error in the example code in chapter 1.9 in the classic book "The C Programming Language"?

Tags: c, overflow, kernighan-and-ritchie

In the Chapter 1.9 in the classic book about C language "The C Programming Language" by Brian & Dennis, there is a bunk of code about a function 'getline' which is used to copy the next line of input text into a char type string and check the overflow. I quote the code below:

```
int getline(char line[], int maxline);
int getline(char s[], int limit)
{
    int c,i;
    for (i=0; i<limit-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i) /* ** */
        s[i]=c;
    if (c == '\n') {
        s[i]=c;
        ++i;
    }
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}
```

Here is the problem: the parameter 'limit' is the max length of the line, so the array s[] can only contain a collection of elements from s[0] to s[limit-1]. If the last character for the  variable c to getchar() is '\n' and this character's index is limit-1, then the judgement part in the 'for' loop will fail because of 'i==limit-1' but not 'c!='\n' (according to the sequence from left to right). Next, if clause will work, because of 'c=='\n'', then s[limit-1]=c, then ++i will set the value of i into limit. s[i]='\0' will overflow, because s[limit] overrun the limit of string. Is my analysis right or not? Thanks for any helpful answers.

Comment: "If the last character for the variable c to getchar() is '\n' and this character's index is limit-1" - that character isn't being read if `i` has reached `limit-1`. Short-circuit boolean eval will break the loop before `getchar()` and the ensuing assignment and further comparison happen.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I missed this point. Thanks.

Comment: There are actually two points where this happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is wrong. If `i == limit-1`, the loop breaks without reading into `c`, due to short-circuit evaluation. So, you never enter `if (c == '\n')`. `i` remains `limit-1` and there is no overflow.

Conceptually, you can think of the loop condition like this: "If `i` is lower than `limit-1`, read a character, and if it's not EOF or newline, enter the loop body." Thus, if `i` is `limit-1`, you never read.

Answer (score 3):

There are two short circuited eval-points points in this code. See below

```
for (i=0; i<limit-1 && (c=getchar())!=EOF && c!='\n'; ++i)
//        (   A   )    (        B        )   (  C  )
```

All are separated with a chain of `&&`. When this code executes, all three must be true or the loop will break. But with short circuit eval the following happens:

- If **A** is false, the condition is false, *neither* B nor C are evaluated.
- Else if **B** is false, the condition is false and C is not evaluated.
- Else if **C** is false, the condition is false.

Therefore...

- if `i<limit-1` is false, *neither* the `getchar()` and comparison against EOF, nor the comparison against `'\n'` are performed.
- else if `(c=getchar())!=EOF` is false, then the comparison against `'\n'` is not performed.
- else the comparison against `'\n'` is performed.

i hope that made sense.